# how to remove a blank space in an input field with having fixed length

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery code:

```
$("body #fuid, #muid").on('keypress change', function ()
        {
            $(this).val(function (index, value)
                {
                    return value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
                });
        });
```

I have an html code like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="father_uid">Father's Aadhar Number (Optional)</label>
    <input type="text" minlength="14" maxlength="14" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" class="form-control" id="fuid" name="father_uid" placeholder="Enter Father's Aadhar Number">
</div>
```

The jquery code works fine but as we can see I have added an attribute of maxlength=14 i.e it should not accept characters after 14 lengths, but according to my jquery code as soon as I enter the 14th character it gives a space at end breaking the max length count, I cannot add characters at the end by myself as it is not accepting it.

Any helps appreciated

```
Current Output: 1234 6789 6788 (With a blank space additionally added at end)
Desired Output: 1234 6789 6788(With no blank space additionally added at end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just trim it before returning. This will remove the last char if it's greater than 14 characters and do nothing if it is not. You may need to adjust the number some if there's more or less characters in the value before you format it:

```
var substringLength = 14;
if (value.length < 14){
    substringLength = value.length;
}
return value.replace(/\W/gi, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').substring(0, substringLength);
```

Comment: your code is working perfectly only one thing is happening that after the limit is reached to 14 now it trims it but if I type any other number the last number gets replaced Ex: 1234 5678 1234 now it has reached the max limit and the field has last number 4 now if I press 5 then 4 gets replaced by 5 how to fix this occurrence & also when the focus is away from the field it removes the last number i.e making the 12 digit number to 11.

Comment: I am actually not on my dev machine at the moment, but I think that might be a result of your regex? Perhaps you could post a fiddle with your field and code so we can tinker with it?

Answer (score 0):

I modified you a code little bit, problem was due to `.replace` where you are replacing with `$1`

```
 var foo = $(this).val().split(" ").join(""); 
  if (foo.length > 0) {
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join(" ");
  }
  $(this).val(foo);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/avhsz7ec/